# Visual Studio 2022 ASP.Net Web Site (Razor v3) template

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to create ASP.Net Web Site (Razor v3) template project as shown below but the template is missing in a new fresh install of Visual Studio 2022.

[image]

I have installed ASP.NET and web development, .NET desktop development and double checked that .NET Framework project and item templates is installed.

Which feature installs this template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open Visual Studio Installer
2. Locate the Visual Studio 2022 card and click "Modify"
3. On the right, in the "Installation details" menu, under "ASP.NET and web development" and then "Optional", check "Additional project templats (previous versions)"
4. Click "Modify" and you'll be done